# how to find file size in windows-mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How i can find file size in windows mobile ? (using c#)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Length property of a FileInfo class:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(pathToMyFile);
if(fi.Exists)
    long sizeOfMyFile = fi.Length;
```